# New Activaction

Tags: icloud, user-account

I bought a iPod 5 over the summer as a Christmas gift for my daughter. I purchased it from an estate sale; as it appeared to be in working order. However, my daughter tryed to setup her own iCloud account yesterday and received a message saying "This iPod belongs to m......@icloud.com enter password". I have no idea what her password is and don't remember where the sale was, what can I do?

Comment: nothing, use it as paper weight. But if you know the email send one to it and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

This question is answered numerous times in just about every corner of the Internet. As a safety feature the iPod is locked to the owner before since they set a password. There is no legitimate method of recovery. Sorry you got duped.